# I need to alter this Matlab Gaussian elimination program to change the form of the final matrix before back substitution

Tags: matlab, matrix

[image: General form of matrix]

[image: Required form of matrix]

I have made this Matlab function that performs Gaussian elimination however, I need to alter my code so that the final matrix (C) before back substitution is in the form of the linked picture named 'Required form of matrix'(where it says A = ).

Right now my code performs Gaussian elimination however the matrix is in the form of the other picture(with u's).

I have tried to change the two for loops in the beginning by saying:

```
for i = n-1:1

 for k = n:i+1
```

However, this has not worked.

Please can you help me

My code:

```
function x = gaussElimination(A, b)


A = [3 1 -1; 1 -4 2; -2 -1 5]; % Inputting the value of coefficient matrix

b = [3; -1; 2]; % Inputting the value of coefficient matrix


[n, n] = size(A);     % Find size of matrix A

[n, k] = size(b);     % Find size of matrix b

x = zeros(n,k);      % Initialize x


for i = 1:n-1
    for k = i+1:n
        m = -A(k,i)/A(i,i); % multiplier
        A(k,:) = A(k,:) + m*A(i,:);
        b(k,:) = b(k,:) + m*b(i,:);
    end
end

C = [A b] % Final form of matrix before back substitution


% Use back substitution to find unknowns
x(n,:) = b(n,:)/A(n,n);
for i = n-1:-1:1
    x(i,:) = (b(i,:) - A(i,i+1:n)*x(i+1:n,:))/A(i,i);
end


end
```

Comment: Please edit your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60261467/how-can-i-alter-this-matlab-gaussian-elimination-program-to-change-the-from-of-t) rather than posting a new one. If the edited question is answerable it will be reopened.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I edited my previous question however it still says 'closed'

Comment: Give it some time, it needs to collect 3 reopen votes.

Comment: Exact duplicate by same author. [I need to alter my Matlab Gaussian elimination program to change the form of the final matrix before back substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60261467/i-need-to-alter-my-matlab-gaussian-elimination-program-to-change-the-form-of-the)

Comment: Don't re-ask questions that got closed. It wastes the time of volunteers and goes against Stack Overflow policy.

Comment: @ModusTollens Ok but now they are both closed so i cant get any answers. Please open one of them